# convert sql query to sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't convert the query I wrote the sql query to sequelize.
This is the query I want to convert;

```sql
SELECT
sum(document_details.qty)'miktar',
stocks.id,
stocks.`name`
FROM
document_details
INNER JOIN documents ON documents.id = document_details.document_id
INNER JOIN stocks ON document_details.stock_id = stocks.id
WHERE documents.warehouse_id = 1
GROUP BY document_details.stock_id
```

This is the query I wrote. However, I only get one data. The output must come in more than one

```js
const {id} = req.query;
        const {limit, page, sortColumn, sortType, search} = req.body;
        Documents.hasMany(DocumentsDetail, {foreignKey: "document_id"})
        DocumentsDetail.belongsTo(Stocks, {foreignKey: "stock_id"});

        const DocumentsList = await Documents.findAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: (page - 1) * limit,
            order: [
                [sortColumn, sortType]
            ],
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    {
                        warehouse_id: id
                    },
                    {
                        id: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: DocumentsDetail,
                    attributes: [
                        "stock_id",
                        "name",
                        [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('qty')), 'total'],
                    ],
                    group: ["stock_id"]
                },
            ],

        });
        res.json({
            total: total.length,
            data: DocumentsList,
            warehouse_name
        });
```

How can I fix? Or what is the truth? can you help?

Comment: Your SQL looks like illogical. You use comma-style CROSS JOIN. You use `documents` only for checking purposes - if the row with `documents.warehouse_id = 1` exists then the query returns the output (if there exists more than one matched line then the output seems to be incorrect), if not exists then the output will be empty. You must fix this firstly.

Comment: @Akina yes you are right, I changed my sql query. can you look again, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my question. Hope it helps someone else too..

```js
DocumentsDetail.belongsTo(Documents, {foreignKey: "document_id"})
        DocumentsDetail.belongsTo(Stocks, {foreignKey: "stock_id"});

        await DocumentsDetail.findAll({
            attributes: [
                [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('qty')), 'quantity'],
            ],
            where: {
                "$document.warehouse_id$": id,
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Documents,
                },
                {
                    model: Stocks,
                },
            ],
            group: ["stock_id"],
        }).then((data) => {
            let opt = {
                total: data.length,
                data: warehouse_name,
                warehouse: data
            }
            res.json(opt);
        })
```